# how to log to graylog from google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, graylog2

I have an application running on google appengine.
I am trying to log to greylog2 from appengin(I do not want to use the app engine cloud logging but greylog)

here is the dependency on my pom:

```
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.graylog2</groupId>
         <artifactId>gelfj</artifactId>
         <version>1.1.15</version>
      </dependency>
```

and here is my code:

```
    GelfMessage message = new GelfMessage("myMessage", "myMessage", new Date().getTime(), "1");
    message.setHost("appspot");
    message.setVersion("1.3");
    message.setFacility("F");
    GelfUDPSender gelfUDPSender;
    gelfUDPSender = new GelfUDPSender("my-ip-address", 12202);
    GelfSenderResult result = gelfUDPSender.sendMessage(message);
```

when I run this locally it works. But when I run this on appengine I see the following message:

```
Error for /worker
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel is a restricted class. 
Please see the Google App Engine developer's guide for more details.
        at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.shared.stub.java.nio.channels.DatagramChannel.<clinit>(DatagramChannel.java)
        at org.graylog2.GelfUDPSender.initiateChannel(GelfUDPSender.java:31)
        at org.graylog2.GelfUDPSender.<init>(GelfUDPSender.java:27)
```

**EDIT:**  graylog works with firewall.
I need to open a route for the appengine instance IP.
does  it have an IP?

is there any way  to get the ip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  could not use the `org.graylog2` jar since it isn't in the [The JRE Class White List](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) sould be using `java.net.URLConnection` instead. see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/issue-requests)

2) accourding to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/) :

> App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses
>   to an application